# Sale tag not visible on configurable products

Tags: magento2

[image]

[image]

The first image is configurable, the 2nd one is a single image.
Now the sale tag is not visible on configurable products.

Can I fix this? And how.

Comment: i have a solution

Comment: please post you code where does this appy. I need that to recode for you

Comment: Thanks. The code of configurable products? Or what exactly?

Comment: from where this sale icon applied. from block or  phml or plugin or what. that code need.

Comment: Have you find??

Comment: no, i just can find the CSS. What is the easy't way to find the file? I tried Google Console.

Comment: are you developer???

Comment: I've got the final_price.phtml. You need that one?

Comment: Just let me know are you developer. Otherwise it will hard to make you understand what i actually need. And this does not work out like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102530/discussion-between-joost-and-padhiyar-gaurang).

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
class ABC{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone
     */
    protected $localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone $localeDate,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    )
    {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
    * \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    */
    public function getLabels($product)
    {
        if($this->_hasSpecialPrice($product)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check if product has special price
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _hasSpecialPrice($product)
    {
        if($product->getData('type_id') == 'configurable'){
            $productTypeInstances = $product->getTypeInstance();
            // Do not this method it caches which comes with not updated data some times
            // $usedProductss = $productTypeInstances->getUsedProducts($product);
            $usedProducts = $productTypeInstances->getUsedProductCollection($product);
            foreach ($usedProducts as $child) {
                $_childProduct = $this->_productModel->load($child->getData('entity_id'));
                $specialPrice = $_childProduct->getData('special_price');
                if ($specialPrice !== null && $specialPrice !== false && $this->isScopeDateInInterval($_childProduct->getData('special_from_date'),$_childProduct->getData('special_to_date'))) {
                        return true;    
                }   
            }
        }

        $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
        if ($specialPrice !== null && $specialPrice !== false && $this->isScopeDateInInterval($product->getData('special_from_date'),$product->getData('special_to_date'))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Check scope interval
    */
    protected function isScopeDateInInterval($fromDate,$toDate)
    {
        return $this->localeDate->isScopeDateInInterval(
            \Magento\Store\Api\Data\WebsiteInterface::ADMIN_CODE,
            $fromDate,
            $toDate
        );
    }
}
```